# Connect consul agent to consul

Tags: docker, consul

I'm trying to setup the consul server and connect an agent to it for 2 or 3 days already. I'm using docker-compose.

But after performing a join operation, agent gets a message "*Agent not live or unreachable*".

Here are the logs:

```
root@e33a6127103f:/app# consul agent -join 10.1.30.91 -data-dir=/tmp/consul
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Joining cluster...
Join completed. Synced with 1 initial agents
==> Consul agent running!
Version: 'v1.0.1'
Node ID: '0e1adf74-462d-45a4-1927-95ed123f1526'
Node name: 'e33a6127103f'
Datacenter: 'dc1' (Segment: '')
Server: false (Bootstrap: false)
Client Addr: [127.0.0.1] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600)
Cluster Addr: 172.17.0.2 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false
==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:
2017/12/06 10:44:43 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: e33a6127103f 172.17.0.2
2017/12/06 10:44:43 [INFO] agent: Started DNS server 127.0.0.1:8600 (udp)
2017/12/06 10:44:43 [INFO] agent: Started DNS server 127.0.0.1:8600 (tcp)
2017/12/06 10:44:43 [INFO] agent: Started HTTP server on 127.0.0.1:8500 (tcp)
2017/12/06 10:44:43 [INFO] agent: (LAN) joining: [10.1.30.91]
2017/12/06 10:44:43 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: consul1 172.19.0.2 2017/12/06 10:44:43 [INFO] consul: adding server consul1 (Addr: tcp/172.19.0.2:8300) (DC: dc1)
2017/12/06 10:44:43 [INFO] agent: (LAN) joined: 1 Err: <nil>
2017/12/06 10:44:43 [INFO] agent: started state syncer
2017/12/06 10:44:43 [WARN] manager: No servers available
2017/12/06 10:44:43 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No known Consul servers
2017/12/06 10:44:54 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect consul1 has failed, no acks received
2017/12/06 10:44:55 [ERR] consul: "Catalog.NodeServices" RPC failed to server 172.19.0.2:8300: rpc error getting client: failed to get conn: dial tcp <nil>->172.19.0.2:8300: i/o timeout
2017/12/06 10:44:55 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: rpc error getting client: failed to get conn: dial tcp <nil>->172.19.0.2:8300: i/o timeout
2017/12/06 10:44:58 [INFO] memberlist: Marking consul1 as failed, suspect timeout reached (0 peer confirmations)
2017/12/06 10:44:58 [INFO] serf: EventMemberFailed: consul1 172.19.0.2
2017/12/06 10:44:58 [INFO] consul: removing server consul1 (Addr: tcp/172.19.0.2:8300) (DC: dc1)
2017/12/06 10:45:05 [INFO] memberlist: Suspect consul1 has failed, no acks received
2017/12/06 10:45:06 [WARN] manager: No servers available
2017/12/06 10:45:06 [ERR] agent: Coordinate update error: No known Consul servers
2017/12/06 10:45:12 [WARN] manager: No servers available
2017/12/06 10:45:12 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No known Consul servers
2017/12/06 10:45:13 [INFO] serf: attempting reconnect to consul1 172.19.0.2:8301
2017/12/06 10:45:28 [WARN] manager: No servers available
2017/12/06 10:45:28 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No known Consul servers
2017/12/06 10:45:32 [WARN] manager: No servers available . `
```

My settings are:
docker-compose SERVER:

```
consul1:
image: "consul.1.0.1"
container_name: "consul1"
hostname: "consul1"
volumes:
- ./consul/config:/config/
ports:
- "8400:8400"
- "8500:8500"
- "8600:53"
- "8300:8300"
- "8301:8301"
command: "agent -config-dir=/config -ui -server -bootstrap-expect 1"
```

Help please solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you using wrong ip-address of consul-server

- "consul agent -join 10.1.30.91 -data-dir=/tmp/consul"

10.1.30.91 this is not docker container ip it might be your host address/virtualbox.

Get consul-container ip and use that to join in consul-agent command.

For more info about how consul and agent works follow the link

https://dzone.com/articles/service-discovery-with-docker-and-consul-part-1

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the right IP address by executing this command:

```
 docker inspect <container id> | grep "IPAddress"
```

Where the  is the container ID of the consul server.

Than use the obtained address instead of "10.1.30.91" in the command

```
consul agent -join <IP ADDRESS CONSUL SERVER> -data-dir=/tmp/consul
```